# How to use plugin options with imagemin-cli?

Tags: svg, npm-scripts, imagemin

I'm trying to use imagemin-cli for npm scripts, but there is no documentation for using plugin options.

The plugin I want to use is *svgo* and the option is `removeDimensions=true`, how would this look as an npm scripts command?

This is an example of a command I ran unsucessfully:

`imagemin [--plugin=svgo --option=removeDimensions=true] src/img/** --out-dir=dist/img/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagemin-cli now supports a way to pass those options; some examples from the [Readme](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-cli):

```
$ imagemin --plugin.pngquant.quality={0.1,0.2} foo.png > foo-optimized.png
$ imagemin --plugin.webp.quality=95 --plugin.webp.preset=icon foo.png > foo-icon.webp
```

Here are some examples that I'm currently using:

```
$ imagemin --plugin.jpegoptim.progressive=true --plugin.jpegoptim.max=70 *.jpg --out-dir=./output
$ imagemin --plugin.pngquant.quality={0.5,0.7} *.png --out-dir=./output
```

If you're interested in the details, this was added in [PR 23](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-cli/pull/23).